# Glide change the cache key of dynamic url

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I am trying to use Glide to load an image from the server. But the problem is dynamic URL and  every time I open the page, it load the same image from server

this is my code

```
@android.databinding.BindingAdapter("imageurl")
public static void loadImageFromUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
    if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) return;

    GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url, new LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + NetworkConstant.TOKEN).build());

    View parent = imageView.getRootView();
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) parent.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(glideUrl).listener(new RequestListener<GlideUrl, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, GlideUrl model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideUrl model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.e("IsFromCache", isFromMemoryCache + " : firstResource" + isFirstResource);

            if (progressBar != null && progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
            .fitCenter()
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, figure it out by changing cache key

```
public class GlideNoTokenUrl extends GlideUrl {

public GlideNoTokenUrl(URL url) {
    super(url);
}

public GlideNoTokenUrl(String url) {
    super(url);
}

public GlideNoTokenUrl(URL url, Headers headers) {
    super(url, headers);
}

public GlideNoTokenUrl(String url, Headers headers) {
    super(url, headers);
}

@Override
public String getCacheKey() {
    String url = toStringUrl();

    if (url.contains("?")) {
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
    }
    return url;
}
```

}

Comment: I can't get this to work with Glide 4.8.0. Do you know how you would implement it with that version?

Comment: You can just extends GlideUrl and override getCacheKey method and return the key you want

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I was trying to make it the default by registering it in the AppModule, but I found it too difficult. I ended up making a kotlin extension function in addition to `load()` called `loadUrlWithToken()` which then uses GlideNoTokenUrl

Comment: Yes. You also can use with the load. Instead of passing URL, you can pass GlideNoTokenUrl(URL) as parameter

Comment: Yeah that's what I do in the extension function. The aim is to help other developers see that they should use GlideNoTokenUrl  in the autocomplete since loadUrlWithToken is highlighted